# How do you create a datetime picker for Kentico that only selects year and months?

Tags: kentico

I want to create a datetime picker in kentico that will select only year and months. How would I do this? 
Kentico version 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Calendar OOTB, which allows you to select specific day, and then when retrieving data read only what you need. Otherwise feel free to create your custom form control, you can read more about it [in documentation.](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/developing-form-controls/example-developing-custom-form-controls)

Answer (score 0):

You can try two options here

- Create your own user control which to create datetime picker using asp calendar control and write your logic there to limit it to month and year only. Check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-datetimepicker-control-in-asp-net/)
- You can create a simple Text Box form control and then use JQuery/Bootstrap datetime picker using some JS code(see below) which I think is easy.

  ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
      $('#datepicker').datepicker( {
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      dateFormat: 'MM yy',
      onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
          $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
      }
      });
  });
  ```